# How to remove unnecessary blank space that shows after Number from input type

Tags: php, sql, removing-whitespace

I've got a problem while trying to edit a database record via PHP. Here it is the code of input type :

```
Employee Code : <input type=\"text\" name=\"empl_kode\" value=\"$edit->EMPL_KODE\">
```

After i successfully adding and showing new record, I've got a problem while editing it. In **Employee Code** text box, after the Number, there is ***long unnecessary white space***.

**Example :**

[image]

How do i remove that unnecessary white space? Should i use trim function?

Comment: you should find how it got in to the variable in the first place.

Comment: @Dagon : i find how it got unnecessary white space ! from the beginning, i choose a wrong data type when build the table. I use char/varchar for numbering.

Answer (score 0):

use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
from the manual.

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and
>   end of a string

```
trim($edit->EMPL_KODE)
```

plus you should find how it got in the variable in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**[trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

**[rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)** — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

Any of the function you can use to trim whitespace from the right side of the string.

**Syntax will be like**

```
trim($edit->EMPL_KODE);
rtrim($edit->EMPL_KODE);
```

Comment: not working. After i add trim, the data show like this :

`trim(20002               )`